# send follow request to protected user in twitter

Tags: twitter, tweepy, twitter-follow

I am using Tweepy to automatically send follow request to twitter users who have protected profile. But I get *Not authorized* exception while using `api.create_friendship(uid)` method. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no API method to enable you to do this. The requests have to be acknowledged via the Twitter website.